# Creating a signalR client HubConnection with Powershell

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, nuget, signalr

I am trying to connect to a SignalR hub using a powershell script. I am very new to powershell, so please excuse any rookie mistake.

I have set up a minimal **not** working example of what I have tried here :
[Gist](https://gist.github.com/dizco/fc8e0a5dcfb09075753b18044722c2a4)

## Relevant code:

### Load dlls

```
$dllFolder = -join((Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName, "\bin\Debug\")
[string[]] $dllPathsToLoad = @("\Newtonsoft.Json.dll", "\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.dll")
$token = "insertyourtokenhere"

function LoadDllPaths($dlls)
{
    foreach ($dll in $dlls)
    {
        $dllpath = $dllFolder + $dll
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($dllpath)
    }
}
[...]
LoadDllPaths($dllPathsToLoad)
```

### Create HubConnection:

```
$server = "https://localhost/rest/"
[...]
$hub = New-Object Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HubConnection($server)
```

### Steps:

1. Create a new Visual Studio project
2. Add Newtonsoft.Json v10.0.2 Nuget package (latest)
3. Add Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client v2.2.2 Nuget package (latest)
4. Add powershell script to the root of the project
5. With powershell (run as admin), type `.\HubConnectionTestsScript.ps1`

### Result:

[image: output]

[View on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PadRr.jpg)

```
Error : System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Connection..ctor(String url, String queryString)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HubConnection..ctor(String url, Boolean useDefaultUrl)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.AuxiliaryConstructorInvoke(MethodInformation methodInformation, Object[] arguments, Object[] originalArguments)
   at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.ConstructorInvokeDotNet(Type type, ConstructorInfo[] constructors, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand.CallConstructor(Type type, ConstructorInfo[] constructors, Object[] args)
```

[This signalR source code object](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client/Connection.cs) seems to be the problem, I just don't see what part of it can be throwing this error.

## Question:

Why does the error mention Newtonsoft.Json v6.0.0 when [signalR dependencies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client/) say `>=6.0.4`, and I have `10.0.2`?

Am I doing anything wrong in my Powershell script which could be causing this?

Thank you very much! Any help is appreciated at this point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue with some help from a colleague. Sharing the solution here in case anyone ever struggles on the same problem.

It appears that one of SignalR dependencies tries to load an old version of Newtonsoft.Json. We can force it to redirect him to our own instance of Newtonsoft.Json

Inspired by [this gist](https://gist.github.com/JamesRandall/444f3365751edb130bef197f2222cfa5), here is the idea :

When you load your Json Assembly, store it in a variable

```
$newtonsoftAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($dllFolder + "\Newtonsoft.Json.dll")
```

Afterwards, setup the redirect bindings. My best guess is that this intercepts any call to load an assembly, giving us the opportunity to return our own Json assembly instead of letting him fail to find the version he wants (6.0.0 in my case).

```
function RedirectJsonBindings()
{
    $onAssemblyResolveEventHandler = [System.ResolveEventHandler] {
        param($sender, $e)
        # You can make this condition more or less version specific as suits your requirements
        if ($e.Name.StartsWith("Newtonsoft.Json")) {
            Write-Host "Newtonsoft assembly" $e.Name -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
            return $newtonsoftAssembly
        }
        foreach($assembly in [System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()) {
            if ($assembly.FullName -eq $e.Name) {
                return $assembly
            }
        }
        return $null
    }
    [System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.add_AssemblyResolve($onAssemblyResolveEventHandler)

}
```

And finally, at the end of your script, unbind

```
# Detach the event handler (not detaching can lead to stack overflow issues when closing PS)
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.remove_AssemblyResolve($onAssemblyResolveEventHandler)
```

Comment: Saved me a lot of time! Thx!
I've found out that using "Newtonsoft.Json.dll" exactly of version "6.0.4.17603" (basically release 6.0.4 on nuget) I don't need binding redirects, it will just use it.